# Problem in launchimg TopCoder Arena

Tags: 14.04, plugins, icedtea

I have a IcedTea plugin for TopCoder Arena. I used it till a week back. But today when I am trying to launch the arena, it is showing this error

```
Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. This application has not been initialized, for more information, execute javaws from the command line.
```

Anyone, please help in knowing what the problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close all Java applications(browsers etc..) and try clearing your cache from terminal:

> javaws -Xclearcache

Worked for me.

If it doesn't work then wait until someone aswers this question:
[Unable to start topcoder arena in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509566/unable-to-start-topcoder-arena-in-ubuntu-14-04)